# validar spinbox python (No se cual evento se debe lanzar)

Tags: python, tkinter

Deseo validar que en un `spinbox` ***no tenga un valor fuera del rango o que no sea numérico***, he pensado en utilizar una expresión regular y extraer todo lo que sea numérico, pero no se cual seria el evento con el cual la función que tengo que se debe lanzar, encontré un código en esta [pagina](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-spinbox-range-validation/) para realizar lo que deseo pero no entiendo como funciona, entonces tengo las siguientes preguntas ¿como realizo lo que pretendo? ¿Existe algún evento que se ejecute cuando alguien lo edite? como un `onChange` un `triger` o sea un listener.

Este es el elemento

```
        self.totalDefauld = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.totalDefauld.set("10")
        self.populationSpin = tk.Spinbox(self, from_=0, to=100, width=5, bg=colorFive, fg=colorFour, textvariable=self.totalDefauld)
        self.populationSpin.pack(side="top")
```

Esta es la función que agregaría para solucionar mi problema

```
        def validationPopulation (self):
            m = re.search(r'/d+', self.populationSpin.get()).group(0)
            if m > 6 or m < 0: 
                self.populationSpin.set(0)
            else:
                self.populationSpin.set(int(m))
```

Edición:

1. A petición agrego el código que realice , el cual no lo había agregado antes por ser muy simple y por ende creo que en el texto de arriba lo explicaba sin necesidad de él.
2. No copeo el código del enlace porque creo que es mas cómodo ingresar en esa pagina para verlo.

Comment: Por supuesto @Christian que pena fue una pregunta rápida, me apena, y siéntete libre de comentarme que te molesta

Comment: ¿y cómo llenas el spinbox?

Comment: @larous25 podrías poner lo que haz intentado, el código que llevas hasta ahora, si tienes algún error, como llegaste al error, etc, mientras mas detalles y aclaraciones des mejor será tu pregunta.

Comment: @christian Que tenga mucha reputación no lo hace experto en escribir preguntas. Quizá, al igual que yo, se ganó su reputación a través de dar respuestas. Podría, nuevamente al igual que yo, tener poca experiencia haciendo preguntas. Yo cuando hice una pregunta sobre postgresql me faltaron muchas cosas importantes en la pregunta, y tenia más de 1000 de reputación en ese entonces.

Comment: @DanteS. lo siento no había tomado en cuenta eso, pero creo que ya debe de saber como funciona el sitio (esta en el recorrido) >_<

Comment: @Christian gracias por tus comentarios, lo que pasa es que fue una pregunta rápida de viernes a las 9 de la noche y por ende no creí que  fuera necesario tanto para obtener una respuesta rápida, pero creo que tienes razón

Comment: gracias  @DanteS. en parte tienes razón! el problema es que no me tome muy seria la pregunta dada la hora y el cansancio que tenia.

Comment: @tincopasan agregue un código donde creo la instancia del `spinbox` donde muestra le agrego por defecto la variable `totalDefault` (el cual olvide agregar y ahora lo hago)  por el parámetro `textvariable`

Comment: @larous25 no te preocupes yo no soy muy exigente como otras personas, no vote en contra ni reporte la pregunta por que sabia que podias mejorarla :)